# Can I use a define to call the operator <<

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

I have a class with the following overload:

```
template<typename T>
ParamContainer &operator<<(keyValue<T> &couple)
{
  insert(couple.key_, couple.value_);
  return *(this);
}
```

and keyValue

```
  template <typename T>
  struct keyValue
  {
    std::string key_;
    T   value_;
    keyValue(std::string key, T &value): key_(key), value_(value){}
  };
```

and I would like to call my operator << like that:

```
ParamContainer p;

p << ("value", "content") << ("id", 5);
```

So I have tried to define this thing:

```
#define ParamContainer<<(X, Y) ParamContainer<<keyValue(X, Y)
```

or

```
#define ParamContainer::operator<<(X, Y) ParamContainer<<keyValue(X, Y)
```

But it's not compiling:

```
src/TemplateEngine.hpp:48:25: warning: ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name [enabled by default] src/ControllerPost.cpp: In member function 'virtual void ControllerPost::operator()(boost::cmatch&, http::server3::reply&, boost::container::flat_map<std::basic_string<char>, std::shared_ptr<PostParam> >&)':
src/ControllerPost.cpp:32:19: error: expected unqualified-id before '<<' token 
src/ControllerPost.cpp:32:19: error: 'X' was not declared in this scope
src/ControllerPost.cpp:32:19: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/local/include/boost/function/function_base.hpp:92:13: note: 'boost::detail::function::X'
src/ControllerPost.cpp:32:19: error: 'Y' was not declared in this scope
src/ControllerPost.cpp:32:19: error: expected ';' before 'ParamContainer'
src/ControllerPost.cpp:34:3: error: 'm' was not declared in this scope
```

from line 32:

```
  TemplateEngine::ParamContainer m;

  m << ("name", "value");
```

If I can't use C++ symbols I guess I will find an other way

Comment: *"But it's not compiling"* This statement suggests that you're getting a compiler error.  Would you like to share that error with us?

Comment: -1: because this is a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: @abelenky I just edited with the error.
Thanks for the -1

Comment: @Alexis:  I'm trying to help you.

Comment: I wonder whether you could exploit C++'s features and hack something with a true overload (not a define) of this operator taking an intializer list (syntactically `m << {x,y}`). Alternatively you can always just use a function-style function which returns the modified container and can also be chained `(m.add(x,y).add(w,z)`). After all. operators are just syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names of both function-style and constant-style preprocessor definitions must be valid C++ identifiers. They cannot contain the `<<` symbol, so your trick is impossible to do with the preprocessor.